# How to find residues of $\frac{1+z}{1-\sin z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I have to compute an integral:
$$\int_C \frac{1+z}{1-\sin z}$$
where $C$ is the circle of radius $8$.
I would do this way:
the function is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}-\{\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi\}$,
$C$ is homologous to $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$  and the singularities don't intercept the curve so I can use the residue theorem, so: $$\int_C \frac{1+z}{1-\sin z}=2\pi i( Res_{\frac{\pi}{2}}(f)+Res_{\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi}(f)+Res_{\frac{\pi}{2}-2\pi}(f))$$ where $$\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi,\frac{\pi}{2}-2\pi$$ are the only singularities inside the circle of radius $8$.
Now my problem is how to compute the residues: I did this:
$$\frac{1+z}{1-\sin z}=\frac{1+z}{1-\cos(z-\frac{\pi}{2})}\frac{(z-\frac{\pi}{2})^2}{(z-\frac{\pi}{2})^2}=[\frac{1+z}{1-\cos(z-\frac{\pi}{2})}(z-\frac{\pi}{2})^2]\frac{1}{(z-\frac{\pi}{2})^2}$$
now,say $g$ the function in the square brackets. $g$ has a removable singularity at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and hence the residues of $f$ in $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is $g'(\frac{\pi}{2})$. The problem is that $g'$ is not defined in $\frac{\pi}{2}$.
Is there a more elegant way to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try the residue at $z = k\pi/2$ where $k \equiv 1 \mod 4$.  If $w = z - k \pi/2$, near $w=0$ we have 
$$\eqalign{\sin(z) &= \cos(w) = 1 - \frac{1}{2} w^2 + O(w^4)\cr
   \dfrac{1}{1 - \sin(z)} &= \frac{2}{w^2} + O(w^0)\cr
    \dfrac{1+z}{1-\sin(z)} &= (1 + k\pi/2 + w)\left(\frac{2}{w^2}+O(w^0)\right)\cr
    &= \frac{(2 + k \pi)}{w^2} + \frac{2}{w} + O(w^0) } $$
So the residue is the coefficient of $w^{-1}$, namely $2$.